# Laravel : form validation : Error ! An Error Occured

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel and I am working on a Laravel App which has been developped by someone else.

How can I debug a Laravel App which give me an " Error ! An Error Occured." on the top header part of a registration form. The error doesn't indicate any issue with field filling (javascript validation is passed without any problem).

The normal flow of this registration form is to send an email just after the submit button is pressed and to record data in the database, then go on a second page to fill.

This error occur on local but not on our online server. I have setup mailtrap.io in my .env file as follow:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username_number_given_by_mail_trap
MAIL_PASSWORD=password_given_by_mail_trap
```

and it works fine with other functions of the app such as password recovery.

I have activated the Laravel Debug Bar.

I don't have any idea where to start to debug this. Can you please advise ?

Laravel version is 5.0 (initially our app was developped on LAravel 4 and has been rolled out on 5.0).

I suspect this function to give me the error:

```
public function postIndex($origin = '')
    {
        $input = Input::only('title','name','country_id','company','company_website','phone_number','email','message');
        $input['origin'] = $origin;
        $input['ip'] = getIP();
        // Create a new validator instance from our validation rules
        $validator = Validator::make($input, ContactUs::$rules );

        // If validation fails, we'll exit the operation now.
        if ($validator->fails())
            return Redirect::route('contact-us')->withErrors($validator);
        try {
            $contact = ContactUs::create($input);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error', 'An Error Occured.');   
        }
        return Redirect::route('contact-us.show',$contact->token)->with('success', 'We have received your message.');
```

Here is the content of rules included in the ContactUs class:

```
public static $rules = array(
        'title'             => 'required',
        'name'              => 'required',
        'email'             => 'required|email',
        'country_id'        => 'required|exists:countries,id',
        'company'           => 'required',
        'company_website'   => 'required',
        'phone_number'      => 'required',
        'message'           => 'required',
    );
```

PS: I run a Laravel 5.0 App on a Wampserver Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.0.32

Comment: Can you check laravel log file for more detail about error

Comment: @LeenaPatel strangely when i delete the log file and attempt again to submit the form, a new log file is not created. Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you add exactly the output of error which your get

Comment: @YvesKipondo this is what is displayed on the top of the form " Error ! An Error Occured."

Comment: @LeenaPatel  I updated the question

Comment: The error message suggests your validation is failing, right? So look at that.  What does `$rules` look like?  [Check the validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) for your version of Laravel. To make sure logging is working, [manually log something](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#writing-log-messages) at the start of your method.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I don't find the variable $rules in current controller where this class is located. How do I know where the values are recorded ?  I confirm the log is working as I have added manually this (Log::info('Showing user profile for user: ');) and it logged it in a laravel-2018-11-20.log file

Comment: `$rules` seems to be a property in the `ContactUs` class.  If you are using an IDE you can probable shift-click or something like that to jump directly to it.  Once you've found it, edit your question and show us what `$rules` looks like.

Comment: @Don'tPanic edited

Comment: After this  `catch (Exception $e)` and before the `return ... ->with('error', 'An Error Occured.');  ` Can you add `\Log::error($e->getMessage());`? Then check the logs

Comment: @cbaconnier  I got this: ([2018-11-21 12:19:05] local.ERROR: The file "C:\wamp640\www\myapp\storage/app/geoip.mmdb" does not exist or is not readable.) We are using this service to know which country people contact us from. If I comment "$input['ip'] = getIP();"  I still get an error

Comment: Doesn't your initial error come from the try and catch block? It's the same error message if it fails. If so you just go an another error there.

Comment: @cbaconnier I don't think the logic is the problem or the code because this app is functionning properly online. However when I installed by using a compuser update, I am not totally sure composer succeed to install all the dependencies.

Comment: It's not what I said. I'm stating that your error probably comes from `$contact = ContactUs::create($input);` but based on your log, the error message is not related to `$e->getMessage() ` I suggested to add.

Comment: Commenting out `$input['ip'] = getIP();` in `postIndex()` won't stop the `geoip.mmdb` error that @cbaconnier helped you find (though maybe it is also generating errors).  The `geoip.mmdb` error that you quote above is being thrown in the `try{}` bock, so it is coming from the code in `ContactUs::create($input)`.